# Laravel Eloquent Unable To accept large html insert via post

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to insert a large html via post into a mysql database using 
Laravel Eloquent .

When I post smaller html it saves properely .

but when I use post man to post a large html template 
the only response i get is   "Could not get any response from server"
I am trying it on my local host.

```
$app->post('savetemplate', 'templateController@store');
```

here is the eloquent  model to save

```
    $eml= new EmailTemplates();
    $eml->eml_html=(string)$request['eml_html'];
    $result=$eml->save();
```

I have set the data type to Longtext in mysql so file size shouldnt be an issue.

Appreciate your help on figuring out what laravel cant handle a huge post.

Comment: Is your submission large enough that you're hitting the `post_max_size` php.ini limit?

Comment: ok I url encoded the html string and am trying to post it   now I get 441 error the request url is too large   ... but I have changed the apache config to accept larger request ..     I'm not sure should I add so.e kind of header when posting the html=mylong html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a localhost server like XAMPP then:

goto `xampp/php/php.ini`

find the line `post_max_size`

replace it with `post_max_size=750M`

Save the file and restart your Apache Server.

Comment: changed the ini restarted apache  now it is only storing half the html string ..   but  data type is long text in mysql  so it should  save the full html string but it only saves half

Comment: check with `dd($request['eml_html])` if the full data is being passed to your controller.